# How can I include headers for OpenCV in Xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, opencv

I've recently installed OpenCV on my MacBook Air M2 using Homebrew. However, when I checked the directory /usr/local/Cellar/opencv, I couldn't find any OpenCV-related files there. Instead, I discovered that OpenCV seems to be located at /opt/homebrew/Cellar.

I've been trying various methods to include this folder in Xcode without success. Here's what I've attempted:

1. I created a command line tool in Xcode.
2. Then, I used the "Add Files" option to navigate to the necessary OpenCV folder.
   However, after taking these steps, I'm uncertain about what to do next. Could someone please guide me on how to properly integrate this folder into my Xcode project?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up the include parts for your project.
Go to `Build Settings` look for the `header search path` and then add the path to `/usr/local/Cella/opencv/<VERSION>/include` where `<VERSION>` should be replaced by the version of open CV you work with.

What happens here is that we tell the Xcode to look in this path for headers as well as the places it looks by default.

Now I don't recall if you have to setup the link binaries as well with OpenCV but their might be something their when you get to building your project.